# NetSuite BeforeSubmit scriptContext.oldRecord returning null Value

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, user-event

I am trying to get the old Value on a record. My code snippet is as follows :

const beforeSubmit = (scriptContext) => {

```
        var param_Old_Item = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name:'custscript_old_item'});
        var param_New_Item = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({name:'custscript_new_item'});

        var type = scriptContext.type;
        var allowedTypes = [
            scriptContext.UserEventType.CREATE,
            scriptContext.UserEventType.EDIT
        ];
        if (allowedTypes.indexOf(type) == -1) {
            return;
        }
        
        var sub_item_new = scriptContext.newRecord.getValue({
                        fieldId: 'custrecord_item123'
                        }); 
       /* var ChargeRec = scriptContext.oldRecord;
        var sub_item_old = ChargeRec.getValue({
                            fieldId: 'custrecord_item123'
                            }); */
        var sub_item_old = scriptContext.oldRecord.getValue({
            fieldId: 'custrecord_item123' });
        
        log.debug({
            title: 'sub_item_old',
            details: sub_item_old
            });
```

The oldRecord value is throwing an error - TypeError: Cannot read property 'getValue' of null [at Object.beforeSubmit

Please help.

Expecting to get the oldRecord Value in beforesubmit

Answer (score 0):

`oldRecord` will always be `null` during a `CREATE` event. The record is being created, so there is nothing in the database yet to retrieve or compare to.

Comment: Thank you, so much. That did not occur to me. I was so concentrated on syntax error . Thank you, again!